# incrementing by 0.1 javascript

Tags: javascript

incrementing by 0.1 javascript

```js
function img1_min_w(){
 var x = document.getElementById("val_img1_l").value++;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="img1_min_w()" value="+">

<output id="val_img1_l">1</output>
    <p> i want incrementing by 0.1;</p>
```

Comment: So? Whats the problem? `++` increments by 1, you have to add 0.1 yourself.

Comment: it incremen by 1 i want incremen by 0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function addValue() {
  const ADD_VALUE = 0.1;
  let element = document.getElementById("target");
  let value = parseFloat(element.innerHTML);
  
  element.innerHTML = parseFloat(value + ADD_VALUE).toFixed(1);
}
```

```css
button {
  height: 32px;
  width: 64px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <button onClick='addValue();'>Add</button>
</div>
<div id="target">1</div>
```

Comment: i want with button pleas

Comment: Try using divs instead of <output> tag, since it wouldn't work correctly

Comment: please covert you answer with button increment

Comment: Just edited answer, check it out and tell me. It should work :-)

Comment: thnx you so much i work ... but i well delete my question because i get 5 unvoite .. and i well go to your profile and vote you all answer .. you accept?

Comment: Haha, I just come here to help out do whatever you want :p. 

Glad I could help :-) - @Jack King

Comment: You are really great programmer Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Probably

```
var val = parseFloat(document.getElementById("val_img1_l").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("val_img1_l").innerHTML = parseFloat(val + 0.1).toFixed(1); 
// for 1 decimal value... change number for more
```

Comment: Making it `(val + 0.1).toFixed(1)` at the end would make a better looking result. But it works fine.

Comment: Try it again, I changed it to innerHTML instead of .value since .value returns Not a Number (you are accessing a DOM node)

Comment: no working agin .. plase convert you answer to snippet for testing

Comment: @MiGu3X — `value` should return a string since it is an Output Element Node

Comment: i well edit my qeaustion and i well put your code ...ok?

Comment: @Quentin I think <output> element works in a different way, I should check it out though - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp - It seems values inside it are strange and works with a 'for' attribute... I don't know though...

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("val_img1_l").value += 0.1;`

Edit: this is definitely wrong. See the comments :)

Comment: @JackKing his answer is correct. He increments by 0.1 as you have asked. Perhaps your problem is elsewhere? "it is not working" really tells us nothing

Comment: @DylanMeeus It doesn't work. It is only cancatening "0.1" to the current value.

Comment: go to test his code and tell me working or no @DylanMeeus

Comment: Pesky javascripts. Wonder why ++ worked in the example :)

Comment: @jedifans — Because `++` only deals in numbers. `+` deals in numbers or strings depending on the data type of the left hand side.